# Nutch Exception: ''..cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: eclipse, exception, nutch

I followed the steps using this site : http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/RunNutchInEclipse

I encountered a problem while running which that says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
String cannot be resolved to a type
Exception cannot be resolved to a type
System cannot be resolved

at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.main(Crawl.java:53)
```

The build was successful.

I am using nutch 1.4.

Moreover, I would like to tell that i didnt understood the point 3 of section **"Establish the Eclipse environment for Nutch"** and skipped it. I guess the problem lies there only.
Can you please help me as the more I try to resolve it, the more i get frustrated.Trying it from past 2 days.
It's a humble request please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want it to run from eclipse? AFAIK only if you want to modify Nutch code it makes sense to run from eclipse and do all set up. In case if you want to run from eclipse for some reason, 3rd point means: You need to add those path. i.e within plugin folder there are many other folder. You need to manually expand each folder and add src/test and src/java. Ex: there is folder called creative commons. In that there src and within that there is java and test folder. You need to select both. Similarly do for all directories within plugin folder.

Comment: Ohhh.... Thanx a lot man....
<br>That was really helpful..
<br>By the way, i need to know what's happening at the back-end and then thereby accordingly customize it.
<br> Anywayz, thanks. +1 for your comment

Comment: just for knowledge, can i integrate StanfordNLP core with Nutch so as to increase the efficiency of my customized search engine???